# how do I replace < with >= and > with <= and replace <= with > and >= with < if they occur multiple times in the same string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm working on this in PHP. I have a string like this: 
"AND day_1 >= day_2 AND day_1 < day_3" 
and I want to replace the first >= with < and I want to replace the second < with >=

In other words, I want to reverse the date range logic:

"AND day_1 >= day_2 AND day_1 < day_3"

I want reversed to look like this:

"AND day_1 < day_2 AND day_1 >= day_3"

Here's my code:

```
$str = "AND day_1 >= day_2 AND day_1 < day_3";
echo "{$str}<br>";
$old_replace = array(">=", "<=", "<", ">");
$new_replace = array("<", ">", ">=", "<=");
$count = 1;
$str = str_replace($old_replace, $new_replace, $str, $count);
echo $str;
```

When I try to use string replace it does this:

before replace: AND day_1 >= day_2 AND day_1 < day_3
after replace:  AND day_1 <== day_2 AND day_1 <== day_3

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This might not be the best way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to think that too... What I'm trying do is reverse the sql statement programmatically, but now I'm realizing I'd need to change the second AND to and OR and add parenthesis to make the statement be logically reversed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$replacements = Array("<="=>">",">="=>"<","<"=>">=",">"=>"<=");
$str = strtr($str,$replacements);
```

Comment: thanks! That works when I reverse the arguments and put $str first, and $replacement second. But the more I look at this problem, the more it demands of me. Now I discovered for the statement to be truly logically reversed, I need also to change the second AND to and OR and wrap the string in parentheses: the first parenthesis, ( after the first AND and the second parenthesis ) at the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry, I had started with `preg_replace_callback`, and forgot to change the order of arguments. It's good that you were able to figure it out though - so many people on SO seem incapable of that...